# Proper symmetrization for dirac field

Tags: quantum-field-theory

At the moment I'm working with a paper from Kimball A. Milton (a student of Julian Schwinger) and he uses a notation which I can't find anywhere. He wrote:

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}((A_{\nu})_{\cdot} \partial_{\mu}F^{\mu \nu} + (F^{\mu \nu}) _{\cdot} \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}) + \frac{1}{4} F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}$

But what does he mean with this $\cdot$ ? He says that this is the proper symmetrization for fermi-dirac or bose-einstein fields but I can' find anything with this tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're refering to [Schwinger's quantum Action Principle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08091.pdf). If you look at equations (6.68), (6.69) on p.78, then clearly the notation means, for fermionic fields:

$$A.B = \left[A,B\right]$$

and it denotes the commutator. I suppose what he means is that for bosonic fields it denotes the anticommutator.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense if he choos the anticommutator for the bosonic fields. Cause I can't reproduce the free Maxwell-Lagrangian with the commutator. But if I look at (6.68) and (6.69) what about the 1/2?

Comment: @Alpha001 You can multiply the whole Lagrangian by a constant, the equations of motion will remain the same since they are given by a variation principle.   (But I agree his notation is clumsy.)